# Not Able to Connect to OPC UA Server From Docker Container using python

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-container, opc-ua, opc

Intially I am able to Run my Python script to connect to OPC Server (Running in my localhost) from my system and get the data.
But when I create an Docker image of my same python code and run it in the container i get the error saying : **File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 833, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused**

This is the snippet of my code.

```
 client= Client("opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:4840",timeout=2000)
    sleep(2)
    try:
        KeepAlive(client,2000)
        client.connect()
```

Please note I have changed the IP to host.docker.internal instead of 127.0.0.1 as well and the i get different error:

**urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f064d0f0dc0>: Failed to establish a new  connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused**

My Dockerfile looks as below

```
FROM python:latest
#RUN mkdir -p /test/inf
WORKDIR /data_sync
#COPY requirement.txt .
#RUN pip install -r  requirement.txt 
RUN pip3 install opcua
RUN pip install opcua-client
EXPOSE 4840
COPY /data_sync .
CMD [ "python", "Main.py"]
```

This also occurs when i try to connect to Original OPC server with real IP address.
Alwasy at Client.connect() it throws error.

I have check many solution increasing the timeout and all but nothing works.

Tried Linux Container and Windows as well.

I am not understanding why the same piece of code works in computer and not docker. Do i Have to do some settings in docker?

Any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works Fine with asyncua and  asyncua.sync instaed of opcua.